# Unable to login on loading FBLoginView

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook SDK for the first time in iOS. I have tried to follow Facebook Documentations for logging in the user: [Login Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial/) and [Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/).

I am adding `FBLoginView` to new view controller on a button press to prompt user for login. Issue I am facing is that after `FBLoginView` is created, I am immediately taken to two `FBLoginViewDelegate` Methods: **loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:** and **loginView:handleError:**

`loginView:handleError:` states error as `FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled` while I never cancelled any request! Modal popup for login appears for 2 seconds, then dismisses automatically with cancel status.

I am really unable to understand that why it is happening. I am testing it on simulator. I have all 3 keys required in .plist file for Facebook SDK integration. Why request is cancelled automatically? Please help me with this issue.. Thanks.

**Code:**

```
#import "FBLoginViewController.h"

@interface FBLoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation FBLoginViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"basic_info",@"user_photos",@"friend_photos", nil]];
    loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, (self.view.center.x - (loginview.frame.size.width / 2)), 5);
    loginview.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:loginview];
}

#pragma mark - FBLoginDelegate

-(void) loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
    NSLog(@"user info: %@",user);
}

-(void) loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{
     NSLog(@"User logged in");
}

-(void) loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{
     NSLog(@"User logged out");//Logs on console
}

-(void) loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSString *alertMessage, *alertTitle;

    // If the user should perform an action outside of you app to recover,
    // the SDK will provide a message for the user, you just need to surface it.
    // This conveniently handles cases like Facebook password change or unverified Facebook accounts.
    if ([FBErrorUtility shouldNotifyUserForError:error]) {
        alertTitle = @"Facebook error";
        alertMessage = [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error];

        // This code will handle session closures that happen outside of the app
        // You can take a look at our error handling guide to know more about it
        // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
    } else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession) {
        alertTitle = @"Session Error";
        alertMessage = @"Your current session is no longer valid. Please log in again.";

        // If the user has cancelled a login, we will do nothing.
        // You can also choose to show the user a message if cancelling login will result in
        // the user not being able to complete a task they had initiated in your app
        // (like accessing FB-stored information or posting to Facebook)
    } else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
        NSLog(@"user cancelled login");

        // For simplicity, this sample handles other errors with a generic message
        // You can checkout our error handling guide for more detailed information
        // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
    } else {
        alertTitle  = @"Something went wrong";
        alertMessage = @"Please try again later.";
        NSLog(@"Unexpected error:%@", error);
    }

    if (alertMessage) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle
                                    message:alertMessage
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: read this doc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/

Comment: @QualityCoder thankyou for pointing out this doc. But I can't find how to debug for mysterious auto cancellation of login :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange, but it worked for me. In viewDidLoad, I changed initialization of `FBLoginView` from:

```
FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"basic_info",@"user_photos",@"friend_photos", nil]];
```

to:

```
FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
```

Initializing without permissions is bringing up the modal popup for login now.

Comment: hahaha. that was solved by myself. No one is my helper here :P

Answer (score 0):

The problem could have been that you had a nil as the last item in the list.

Comment: Array's last object is always nil.